# Adding binary variables in GLPK

Tags: binary, addition, linear-programming, ampl, glpk

I'm using GLPK under Linux to solve some linear programming problems. In one of my restrictions I have:

```
s.t. example: binary_var+binary_val <=1;
```

Where `binary_val` is a variable defined as 'binary'.

If `binary_val` takes the value `1`, will its sum be `2`, or as it is in binary, will it return either `0` or `1`?

Comment: Forgot to say that I searched in the official reference, without luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `binary_var + binary_val <= 1` then here's what that constraint means:

**Either** `binary_var` or `binary_val` can be 1, but both cannot be **simultaneously** 1. Both can be zero, since the constraint is satisfied.

To answer your specific question, a `binary` variable can only assume values 0 or 1. But the **sum** of two binary variables can be 2.

Comment: Thank you, that last paragrapph was the answer I was looking for!